# Сервер сбрасывает Ajax запросы

Tags: comet, ajax, javascript, php

Здравствуйте. При работе над чатом (с автоматическим обновлением списка сообщений) для организации столкнулся с непонятной ошибкой. На домашнем компьютере обновление работает, на месте нет, просмотр FireBug показал что сервер сбрасывает Ajax запросы. Comet реализован через XMLHttpRequest зацикленный в setTimeout. На сервере запрос обрабатывается Php.

Код клиента:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$user="'.$_REQUEST['user'].'";
$topic="'.$_REQUEST['topic'].'";
$messages_rows="'.$mysql_messages_rows.'";

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

function comet() {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","comet.php?r="+Math.random()+"&user="+$user+"&topic="+$topic+"&messages_rows="+$messages_rows);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState==4)&&(xmlhttp.status==200)&&(xmlhttp.responseText)) {
            $messages_rows++;
            var newtd = document.createElement("td");
            var newth = document.createElement("td");
            if ($messages_rows%2==0) {
                newth.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            } else {
                newtd.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            var newtr = document.createElement("tr");
            newtr.appendChild(newtd);
            newtr.appendChild(newth);
            document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].insertBefore(newtr,document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[$messages_rows]);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    setTimeout(comet, 1000);
}

comet();

</script>
```

Код сервера:

```
<script language='php'>
if (isset($_REQUEST['user'])and($_REQUEST['user'])and(isset($_REQUEST['topic']))and($_REQUEST['topic'])and(isset($_REQUEST['messages_rows']))and($_REQUEST['messages_rows']!=='')) {
    $mysql_host='localhost';
    $mysql_login='root';
    $mysql_password='rootme';
    $mysql_database='type_db';
    $mysql_connect=mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_login,$mysql_password);
    $mysql_select=mysql_select_db($mysql_database,$mysql_connect);
    $mysql_query='SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `topic`="'.$_REQUEST['topic'].'"';
    $mysql_result=mysql_query($mysql_query);
    $mysql_messages_rows=mysql_num_rows($mysql_result);
    if ($mysql_messages_rows>$_REQUEST['messages_rows']) {
        for ($i=0;$i<$_REQUEST['messages_rows'];$i++) {
            $mysql_messages_array=mysql_fetch_array($mysql_result);
        }
        $mysql_messages_array=mysql_fetch_array($mysql_result);
        echo '
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <button style="width: 100%;">
                    <div style="font-style: italic; text-align: left;">Пользователь '.$mysql_messages_array['user'].' в '.$mysql_messages_array['date'].' написал:</div>
                    '.$mysql_messages_array['message'].'
                </button>
                <input type="hidden" name="user" value="'.$_REQUEST['user'].'">
                <input type="hidden" name="topic" value="'.$_REQUEST['topic'].'">
                <input type="hidden" name="message" value="'.$mysql_messages_array['message'].'">
            </form>';
    }
}
</script>
```

P.S. Только что проверил работу скрипта с телефона (Nokia N9, стандартный браузер, WebKit 2 если не ошибаюсь). На нем обновление прекрасно работает. В то время как с компьютеров (тестировал с двух разных компьютеров и со всех популярных браузеров) по прежнему не работает.

Comment: что говорит консоль?

Comment: Консоль FireBug:

GET http://192.168.1.15/comet.php?r=0.61923077604355...0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0&messages_rows=61
Aborted 
index.php (строка 918)

GET http://192.168.1.15/comet.php?r=0.94094805421377...0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0&messages_rows=61
Aborted
index.php (строка 918)

GET http://192.168.1.15/comet.php?r=0.31282387209515...0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0&messages_rows=61
Aborted
index.php (строка 918)

...

Comment: Может из-за того, что на телефоне старый WebKit, не соответствующий современным методам.

Comment: Кстати - вы уверены что вы хотите именно это?

     $user="'.$_REQUEST['user'].'";
     $topic="'.$_REQUEST['topic'].'";
     $messages_rows="'.$mysql_messages_rows.'";

Как я понимаю вы хотели сделать что-то типа

     $user  = "<?= $_REQUEST['user']  ?>";
     $topic = "<?= $_REQUEST['topic'] ?>";
     $messages_rows="<?= $mysql_messages_rows ?>";

Иначе у вас, что-бы вы понимали:

     $user="'.$_REQUEST['user'].'";
     console.log( $user ); // -> '.$_REQUEST['user'].'

Comment: @AlexWindHope, там лимит комментов, отвечу здесь.  
Есть задача. Обновляться раз в секунду. Мы ее можем решить разными способами, как в особенностях реализации, так и разными подходами. 
Мой вариант возможен без рекурсии, никто не спорит, просто я честно говоря не понимаю чем такой вариант плох с точки зрения общего применения, а не только "в случае псевдо параллельного IO". В предельном случае, когда запросы на сервер возвращаются мизерное время и ваш варинат и мой работают примерно одинаково. Это что касается загаженности очереди событий.

Comment: Но если интервал будет увеличиваться (если запрос работает долго), то просто не выполнится задача, мой вариант потребует либо увеличить интервал, либо делать параллельные запросы (что хуже), ваш вариант привете к тому, что мы можем обновление увидеть только через минуту...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov - я понял, спорить с 35 летним программистом гнилое занятие, вы мне пишите о какой-то фантастике, мне проще **тупо** с вами согласиться ибо я не желаю больше тратить время на споры.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я без офенса. Просто мне до сих пор не понятно чем варианты отличаются. Я принимаю оба варианта как решение, но разных задач. Вы решаете задачу "непрерываемый цикл, с одним неконтролируемым запросом", я предложил  решение "непрерывный цикл с отсечением периодически длителельных запросов". И ваш алгоритм можно свести к моему и мой к вашему, зависит от реализации. Вы сказали что мой вариант, грубо говоря, плохой. Я не вижу разницы, показывающей что ваш вариант сколько-нибудь лучше, и хочу действительно понять. Фантастики тут нет никакой, рассматриваем вполне конкретный случай.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout(comet, 1000);

увеличение timeout, должно помочь решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Может лучше

```
setTimeout(comet, 1000);
```

поместить в функцию `onreadystatechange`, чтобы вызывать `comet` не каждую секунду, а по приходу ответа от сервера через секунду

Comment: Тогда цикл опроса может прерваться. Правильнее в отдельной функции ждать был ли ответ, если был запускать снова, если не было ждать некий таймаут. И обрабатывать стоит все-таки не только xmlhttp.status==200...

Comment: Получается что все равно нужен будет таймер для запуска функции, если сервер не ответит, аесли ответит надо будет убить первый таймер, и запускать второй для запуска функции с паузой.

Comment: Зачем таймер ?? Добавьте обработчик onError, onFailure который будет так же как и onSuccess вызывать фун-цию comet тогда ее вызов никогда не оборвется.. хотя я не силен в comet технологии, возможно это не безопасно или сожрет память....

Comment: Александр Смага, Интересно, спасибо за совет, пересмотрю цикл.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, в изначальном коде вижу потенциальную проблему в том, что если запрос не отработает за секунду последует еще один вызов с той же переменной xmlhttp (она глобальная). Видимо в этот момент происходит abort (?). Кроме того, у браузера есть ограничение на количество одновременных запросов и с этой точки зрения правильнее ждать конца запроса, потом отправлять следующий. если честно, не вижу криминала в таком подходе. расскажите, почему так делать не стоит?

Comment: Попробую увеличить таймаут с секунды на... к примеру пять. Отпишусь.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov - я с этим не спорю, но человек дело написал, код должен выглядеть примерно так:

     function comet() {
         // xhr ....
         xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if( this.readyState === 4 ) {
                 setTimeout(comet, 1000);
                 if( this.status >= 200 && status < 300 ) {
                      // DOM manipulation
                 }
             }
         }
     }
   
Насколько я понял - вы имели введу вовсе не это.

@temoffey - это не выход, попробуйте то, что я написал выше

Comment: Как я понимаю - вы имели введу что-то другое, что-то типа - по ответу сервера пишем какой-то флаг, а другая функция по какому-то интервалу ( тауймауту, не суть ) его проверяет. Если да - то здесь этого не нужно и, как я и писал выше - это применимо строго для псевдо паралельного IO и больше нигде.

Если же вы имели введу именно это, тогда мне неясен ваш первый комментарий ( "...Тогда цикл опроса может прерваться...", "... Правильнее в отдельной функции ждать был ли ответ..." )

Comment: @AlexWindHope Ну это просто вариация. Смысл предложенного мной в том, чтоб в любой момент времени был только один запрос, с гарантией сохранения цикла. а где вызывается этот setTimeout не так уж принципиально. Если не так выразился, то вот код, иллюстрирующий мой коммент:

    var ajaxready = ture;
    var timeout = 0;
    function SendComet(){
      timeout++;
      if (timeout>10){
         xmlhttp.abort();
         ajaxready = true;
      }
      if (ajaxready){
         comet();
         timeout = 0;
      }
      setTimeout(SendComet(),1000);
    }

в readystatechange: ajaxready=true

Comment: ,а в comet() ставить ajaxready=false.

**UPD** Да, перечитал ответ. Просто в ответе не указано, что надо отслеживать не только 200 ответ. и запуск оттуда setTimeout только при 200 ответе может привести к обрыву цикла. В общем ясно примерно, что говорим об одном и том же просто недоговоренности мешают. Моя функция, считаю, ничем не хуже чем, а может даже и лучше, не мне судить.

**UPD2** Кстати ваш вариант будет срабатывать больше чем через секунду всегда. мой в случае быстрых ответов всегда через секунду. а при долгих ответах у меня максимум через 10 секунд, у вас ограничения нет.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov - для реализации кода, описанного вами выше достаточно использовать

    var t = setTimeout( function() {
      xhr.abort();
      comet(); 
    }, 1000)

Если ответ пришел - очищаем таймаут и снова вызываем функцию, если нет - запрос сброситься и будет отправлен новый.

А описанный вами паттерн это именно то, о чем я писал выше. В данном конкретном случае - бессмысленная растрата ресурсов процессора и не осмысленное загаживание событийного потока, не более того.

Даже на 100% ваш алгоритм, по человечески - реализовывается без проверки рекурсией (т.е. без watcher'a)

Comment: "запуск оттуда setTimeout только при 200 ответе может привести к обрыву цикла" , я прошу прощение - а где вы это увидели в коде?

Т.к. почистил коммент сверху, по поводу " Кстати ваш вариант будет срабатывать больше чем через секунду всегда", мне для этого достаточно записать timestamp переменную и следующий timeout ( если он сработал по onreadystatechange ) вызывать так, что-бы скорость ответов была адекватной тому, что написали вы. При  всем этом я бы не загаживал IO ( что важнее ) и экономил бы батарейку пользователей моб. устройств( для оных тоже довольно таки важно )

Answer (score 0):

А может надо для обёртки кода PHP использовать не

```
<script language="php">...</script>
```

а

```
<?php ... ?>
```

Может ваш домашний сервер понимает теги `script` для `php` а провайдера сервер нет?

Comment: Понимает. Страница чата и даже сам скрипт на ней генерируется именно Php.
Я конечно попробую и отпишусь.

Comment: Попробовал, ситуация не изменилась.

Comment: Ладно тогда я вам не могу помочь может гуру посмотрят на код и ответят.. А мне надо в лицей за результатами....

Comment: @Rules, это вряд ли...скорее просто от кривых ручек =)

Comment: @Asen, несмотря на то, что код очень далек от идеала - это явно не то, о чем ты писал.

*вы творите какое-то безумие в функции comet()..."псевдорекурсия", что ли"...* - улибнуло :)

Answer (score 0):

Да уж...вы творите какое-то безумие в функции `comet()`! Вы прямо из неё вызываете:

```
   setTimeout(comet, 1000);
```

Т.е её саму! Получается полный бред...какая-то "псевдорекурсия", что ли =)

---

Попробуйте Это:

```
  setTimeout(comet, 1000);
```

Вынести в отдельную функцию и уже в самом конце клиентского кода вызывать не `comet()`, а эту самую функцию:

```
  function start()
 {
     setTimeout(comet, 1000);
 }

 ....
 start();
 </script>
```

---

А вообще( так, небольшой совет ) используйте jQuery! Он поддерживает работу с Ajax, да при чем как! Весь ваш клиентский код можно было бы сократить до 10-15 строчек

Comment: Рекурсия и есть.

Comment: Окей, тогда вопрос, зачем она **здесь** ?

Comment: По поводу Попробуйте Это: сейчас пробую.
По поводу Зачем она здесь: необходим частый опрос сервера о наличие новых сообщений. Рекурсия setTimeout позволяет выполнять функцию через определенное время после завершения предыдущего выполнения функции.

Comment: Нет, раз вы так рассуждаете, то мало что знаете о рекурсии( если вообще что-то знаете ), к сожалению...здесь я вам точно скажу - рекурсия неуместна! Да и плюс ко всему, она сильно сжирает память( особенно в вашем случае ), так что это надо исправлять, срочно!

Comment: Попробовал. Телефон - работает, компьютеры - нет, по прежнему в FireBug и прочих отладчиках пишет что запросы прерваны.

Comment: Можете предложить что нибудь по замене рекурсии?

Comment: "здесь я вам точно скажу - рекурсия неуместна"

Да ну? Предлагаете long polling сделать? =)

"Он поддерживает работу с Ajax, да при чем как!"

Как? Самым обыкновенным образом

Answer (score 0):

Все что вам насоветовали, все по делу. Мне кажется что проблема в том что url в аякс запросе начинается не со слеша(я имею ввиду может срабатывать политика безопасности браузера в сторону кроссдоменных аякс запросов), попробуйте вместо

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","comet.php?r="+Math.random()+"&user="+$user+"&topic="+$topic+"&messages_rows="+$messages_rows);
```

поставить

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/comet.php?r="+Math.random()+"&user="+$user+"&topic="+$topic+"&messages_rows="+$messages_rows);
```

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
это точно не кроссбаузерное решение!

От себя хотел добавить:

1. Используйте jQuery.post его синтаксис очень понятен и самое главное это кроссбраузерно
2. Как уже говорили используйте полные php теги т.е. <?php ?> и ничего другого! Пока в силу не войдет php 5.4... тогда можно уже и <? использовать
3. Не используйте mysql_connect, mysql_query и т.д. Используйте хотябы PDO и его prepare statement, или вообще перейдите раз и навсегда допустим на Zend_Db или чтото подобное! во первых это безопаснее, во вторых ваш код станет читабельным
4. Не используйте $_REQUEST используйте те глобальные массивы в которых вы ожидаете переменных, в противном случае  когда нибудь все смешается... кони, люди ...

Ну и на последок, удачи !

Comment: Да и еще один bad practice передача HTML в responseText, Используйте json, xml что удобнее...

Comment: По поводу Начинается не со слеша: Попробовал, не изменилось. Дома работает везде, на работе - только на телефоне.

Comment: По поводу От себя добавить: Используя JQuery, Zend и прочие фреймворки то на неопределенное значение снижается производительность. Дря разовой задачи возможно не критично, но в этом случае я решил сделать как можно более оптимизированный код для каждого запроса.

Comment: По поводу Удачи: Спасибо.

Comment: @temoffey, почитал все обсуждение. Такое впечатление, что ошибка не в коде, а настройках сервера. А может быть у Вас 2 разных сервера принимают запросы (на работе один, а из внешнего мира другой), а потом переадресуют на третий, где реально запрос исполняется ? 

При этом внешний сервер все нормально пропускает, а внутренний часть запросов отвергает.

Comment: Дома поднимаю на ноутбуке, второй ноут через Wi-Fi роутер цепляется. Запросы работают с обоих, и сообщения обновляются.
На работе сервер на стационарнике, на нем параллельно принтер и файлопомойка. К нему по проводу роутер, а к роутеру остальные компы, кто по проводу, кто по Wi-Fi. Нигде кроме телефона не работает.

Comment: И там и там Windows, Apache, MySql и PHP. Настройки стандартные, версии одинаковые.

Comment: Домашний ноут с Apaсhe (сервер) принести на работу, подключить его к местной LAN и запрашивать с него не пробовали ? 

Нет ли на работе какого-нибудь "*хитрого*" файервола ?

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, решилось увеличением таймаута. Что бы предотвратить подобное в дальнейшем поправил код по примеру [@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov).